# How to use a sed command on every line in a file?

Tags: linux, sed, foreach, command, xargs

```
sed -i -e '/line/a\/to be added/' argument
```

1. Argument is every line of a file [These lines have path to multiple text files]. Can I use foreach in linux terminal? What are other options?
2. I tried xargs the following way but didn't work
   xargs -a file_name -I{} -d'\n' sed -i -e '/line/a/to be added/' {}
   Where am I going wrong above?

Ex : file.txt contains paths of various files - one per line
I want to apply sed command on all the files present in file.txt

Comment: I don't understand your question. `sed` already processes every line in the file whose name you pass as final parameter.

Comment: Please show a minimal before and after example.

Comment: I edited my question to be more clear

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU parallel and sed):

```
parallel -q sed -i '/line/a\/to be added/' :::: argument
```

This will append a line `/to be added` to each line which contains `line` for each file in the file called `argument`

Answer (score 0):

This question is more about how to use a foreach loop to read line by line from a file in bash:

You can do that with `while read` and redirecting the file with `< file`.

Here's an example:

```
while read line; do
  sed -i -e '/line/a\/to be added/' $line
done < argument
```

argument is your text file, just like in your question.

Comment: How can I give command with multiple lines in a terminal?

Comment: The simplest way, you don't.  Just put `;` in instead of line breaks and write it on one line. But if you really have to, it differs a little between terminal interpreters and systems. A way that often works is pressing CTRL+X+E and an editor should open. It then will run whatever you type in after closing it.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the `sed` command into the file and execute from there

Using GNU `sed e` option which executes the command that is found in pattern space and replaces the pattern space with the output.

```
$ sed  's~^~sed -i.bak "/line/a\/to be added/e" ~' input_file
```

Or

```
$ sed  's~^~sed -i.bak "/line/a\/to be added/" ~' input_file | sh
```